# R readr: pasing arguments to cols() from a list?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

How do I feed the ... argument of `cols()` when my input comes from a list?

Context: I want to indicate the column types of a data to be read with `readr::readr`, specifying the `cols` arguments. This would go like `cols(Sepal.Length=col_number(), Sepal.Width=col_number())`. However, these column types are retrieved from a list, and I do not see how I can input that list into the `cols()` function?

```
## standard case:
library(readr)
cols(Sepal.Length="n", Sepal.Width="n")
cols(Sepal.Length=col_number(), Sepal.Width=col_number())

## now input is defined in a list instead:
li_cols <- list(Sepal.Length="n",
            Sepal.Width="n")

## how do I pass this to cols? This won't work:
cols(unlist(li_cols))
cols(li_cols)
```

Comment: You can use `do.call`. `do.call(cols, li_cols)`.

Comment: Reprex: `read_csv(readr_example('mtcars.csv'), col_types = do.call(cols_only, list(mpg = 'd', cyl = 'c')))` Also, a tidyverse drop-in alternative is `purrr::invoke`.

Comment: awesome, thanks to both of you! Wanna put it it as full answer?